# API level mismatch

Tags: android, api

I'm having a device with API 22. For the below code,

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
 checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

android studio shows and error saying

> Call requires API level 23

`checkSelfPermission` have underlined with red

I want to run the app on API 22. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Set your targetedsdkversion to 23 or higher and compilesdkversion to 23 or lower.